# How can i access TDE enabled column in Java application?

Tags: java, oracle, tde

We are using Oracle TDE to protect sensitive data. We have only enabled TDE on one column. And we want the java application developer to access that sensitive column data in java  code.
But to access the plain text data we need to open the wallet first. For that we need to use ALTER SYSTEM query shown below,
    `ALTER SYSTEM SET ENCRYPTION WALLET open identified by "**********”`;
And our DBA's are refusing to give ALTER SYSTEM permissions to developer, which is correct in application point of view. So my question is, how we access such column in Java code without ALTER SYSTEM permissions? Has anyone faced such problem before? What are the other ways to access such data through java code?

Answer (score 0):

> we need to use ALTER SYSTEM [...]
>   [but] our DBA's are refusing to give ALTER SYSTEM permissions to developer

In the general case, you solve such issue by requesting from your DBA she write a `PROCEDURE` that executes with [*definer rights*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLS/accesscntl.htm#TTPLS274), encapsulating the "problematic" call. Then your DBA will have to grant *you* the execution of that procedure.

Comment: DBA agreeed to keep the wallet open. So we can access the plaintext values through JDBC. Not sure whether keeping the wallet open and accessing the values through JDBC is secure or not.